# Create variable accessible through all templates in PrestaShop

Tags: templates, controller, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I understood that if I want to make my own template variable in PrestaShop, I would use code like this:

```
$this->context->smarty->assign( 'varName', 'varValue' );
```

I also understood that the right way to add this is putting it into a controller... and it all works...

What I can't figure out is how to do this in one place but still being able to access the template variable in ALL templates (my theme's .tpl files)?

PS: Adding it to all controllers seems redundant... I tried to google it out, but I guess I am putting bad keywords to search for...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I found a solution.

What you want to do is to put your variable definition in some "general" controller - for frontend it is the `FrontController`. A better way then to edit the core file, is to make an override so I will show you all you need to do - considering PrestaShop 1.6 :

1. Create a file called `FrontController.php` and put it in `override/classes/controller`
2. Create a content of this file - handy method to override is `initHeader()`, because the variable will be available in `header.tpl` and all templates that are using it
   (tested in `header.tpl` and `index.tpl`).

Content of `override/classes/controller/FrontController.php`:

```
class FrontController extends FrontControllerCore {
    public function initHeader(){
        //create your variable
        self::$smarty->assign('yourVariable', 'valueOfYourVariable');

        //call original method, to maintain default behaviour:
        return parent::initHeader();
    }
}
```

3. Load the override=> go to `cache` directory (from shop root) and edit file called `class_index.php`:

   - find array with key "FrontController" (search for `'FrontController'` or `"FrontController"`)
   - in this array change "WHATEVER" in `'path' => 'WHATEVER',` 
     to `override/classes/controller/FrontController.php` so you will get: 
      `'path' => 'override/classes/controller/FrontController.php',`
4. Use your variable freely in template files as `{$yourVariable}`

**Reference:** http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Overriding+default+behaviors

Answer (score 4):

you can do with modules also, prestashop provides hooks, we can use the header hook inside our module and pass the variables to smarty from the header hook function. The header hook is available on all pages

```
public function hookHeader($params)
{
    $this->smarty->assign(array('var1' => 'value 1', 'var2' => 'value 2', 'var3' => 'value 3',));
}
```

Comment: That is a nice point (so +1) but understand that I don't want to create module when I am creating basic theme views... :)